Applying Spectral Mapping Theorem to determine if $f(T)$ is compact
Given a self-adjoint, compact operator $T$ and a continuous $f:\sigma(T)\to\mathbb{R}$, I'm trying to determine the conditions under which $f(T)$ is also compact. I know of the Spectral Mapping Theorem, by which $$\sigma(f(T))=f(\sigma(T))$$
As such, we have that the spectrum $f(T)$ is composed of $f(\lambda_i)$ for each $\lambda_i\in\sigma(T)$. In particular, suppose $f(0)=0$, then by continuity, for any non-finite countable subset of $\sigma(f(T))$, there exists a unique accumulation point 0. As such, for any bounded sequence $\{x_n\}$, we have $$\{f(T)x_n\}=\{\sum_{m=1}^\infty f(\lambda_m)P_m(x_n)\}$$ where each term in the sequence defined above is bounded ($<\infty$).
From here, I'm not sure where to proceed and would appreciate any help or guidance on potential directions as well as any potential mistakes.

Hint: $P_m$ are all finite-dimensional, and norm limits of finite-rank operators are compact.

Here is another approach: Note that if $T$ is compact, then $T^n$ is also compact for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and thus $p(T)$ is compact for any polynomial with zero constant term. Write $f\colon\sigma(T)\to\mathbb{R}$ as a uniform limit of polynomials, say $(p_n)$, and deduce that $p_n(T)\to f(T)$ in norm. If $f(0)=0$, then by replacing $p_n$ with $p_n-p_n(0)$, we can assume without loss of generality that $p_n(0)=0$, and thus $f(T)$ is a norm limit of compact operators, and it is therefore compact.
If $f(0)\ne0$, then put $g=f-f(0)$. Note that $g(T)=f(T)-f(0)1_H$, so $1_H$ is a linear combination of $g(T)$ and $f(T)$. Since $g(0)=0$, $g(T)$ is compact by the first part. Therefore, if $f(T)$ was compact, then $1_H$ would be compact, hence $H$ would be finite dimensional.
Conclusion: If $H$ is infinite dimensional, $f(T)$ is compact iff $f(0)=0$. If $H$ is finite dimensional, $f(T)$ is (of course) always compact.
